# Is there a way to have NEXT_PUBLIC_ environment variables exposed when running inside a docker image managed by coolify?

Tags: next.js

I am trying to deploy a next.js app to my own web server managed by coolify, and none of my NEXT_PUBLIC_ variables are exposed even though I check the build variable checkbox in coolify's environment variables. Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Those variables need to be marked as build variables within coolify's ui, and then under advanced there is an option that says force deploy without using cache. This forces next.js to rebuild again and put in the build environment variables.